# Issues with FastCGI and links containing index.php? versus index.php

Tags: iis-6, windows-server-2003, fastcgi, expressionengine

On a Windows 2003 server running IIS 6.0 and FastCGI with an ExpressionEngine-powered website, I've encountered an issue where links containing index.php fail unless a question mark is added.

The basic issue is that if a link points to "index.php/archive/article", the page fails to load (see below) but it will work when "index.php?/archive/article" is used.

What happens when the "index.php" links fail is the URL will change in the browser address bar, but the main page content is still displayed. Append a question mark to "index.php" and the page loads properly.

The site was previously running with ISAPI as the Server API with no issues: the server saw "index.php" and "index.php?" as being synonymous and pages with "index.php" in the path would load as expected.

How would I configure setting somewhere which would tell FastCGI to treat "index.php" and "index.php?" the same way?

I am a bit green when it comes to Windows servers; my experience is mostly with Apache servers running on Unix boxes.

Any guidance or pointers would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One option is that you could simply [enable EE's force URL query string option](http://expressionengine.com/docs/cp/admin/system_preferences/output_and_debugging_preferences.html).

But, if you don't like having the question mark in the URL, you can try [this workaround](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Workaround_for_Forced_Query_Strings/).

I can't say that I know anything about Windows servers, but this has worked for me on Apache servers when running PHP as CGI. Best of luck!